# asp.net core targeting .net framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm adding a new asp.net core project straight from Visual Studio (16.3.2).
I'm Targeting the .net framework and ASP.Net Core 2.2 and making no edits.

[image: Standard new project for asp.net core]

I'm then publishing to Azure app service and see what id expect for the standard new proj.

[image]

Next, I need to reference another library which is built-in .net 4.8 so change the target framework from `net461` to `net48` and republish (prior to adding a reference to the other library.

[image: Upate this to net48]

[image]

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure
```

From some of the reading I can find I see that `The in-process hosting model isn't supported for ASP.NET Core apps that target the .NET Framework.` but it was previously when targeting the earlier version of `net461`?

In the scm console, i can see this event logged.

```xml
<Event>
        <System>
            <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2"/>
            <EventID>1020</EventID>
            <Level>1</Level>
            <Task>0</Task>
            <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-10-08T08:45:18Z"/>
            <EventRecordID>393902093</EventRecordID>
            <Channel>Application</Channel>
            <Computer>RD0003FF6AA327</Computer>
            <Security/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data>Application '/LM/W3SVC/1779341267/ROOT' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to start process with commandline 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Admin.exe ' with multiple retries. Failed to bind to port '8399'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs from multiple retries:
</Data>
            <Data>Process Id: 19244.</Data>
            <Data>File Version: 13.0.19218.0. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 4a42afc5aea63750638e118560d43db04bd9ccc2</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
```

Questions

- Can someone give me a steer in the right direction please?
- Where is the best place to find out about this sort of infomration, does anyone have any helpful links?
- General rant, why is this hard from a simple new project template

Comment: This isn't related to in-process - you don't have that enabled in the csproj and the error message shows "Out-Of-Process Startup Failure". As for what it _is_, that's really difficult to tell at this stage. Have you checked through the logs? It's possible that .NET Framework 4.8 still isn't support in Azure App Services, but I dunno if that's actually the case.

Comment: Why are you targeting .NET Framework in .NET Core project? Target .NET Core.

Comment: I need to reference another library which is built-in .net 4.8

Comment: `Failed to bind to port '8399'` seems to be the critical error here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because .net48 is not installed on Azure App Services yet.
When I downgraded to .net471 is worked. Now the waiting game.

[image: .net frameworks]

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/37566262-upgrade-app-service-with-net-4-8